# removing string on java

Tags: java, string, cut

my question is how to removing character

i want te remove

```
[ "Informasi Seputar Ijazah dan SKHUN SMA"]
```

become

```
Informasi Seputar Ijazah dan SKHUN SMA
```

i've tried

```
String link=object.get("url").toString();
String link2=(link.substring(1, link.length()-1));
```

but the result is only

```
 (space)"Informasi Seputar Ijazah dan SKHUN SMA"
```

any solution guys? thanks before...

Comment: try `String link2=(link.substring(2, link.length()-1));` if you have a space after `[` character in your original string.

Comment: If your question is not so important, then try different options than asking it. Like: doing some prior research.

Comment: its can remove (space) mate, but it cant remove " " , i want remove " " too hehe

Comment: hehe maybe for some java master its not so important, but its very important for me :)
sorry if my words is wrong..

Comment: You could try something like 
`String link=object.get("url").toString();`
`String link2 = link.replaceAll("(\\[|\\]|\")", "").trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Just trim more characters at the start of the string :

```
String link=object.get("url").toString();
String link2=(link.substring(2, link.length()-1));
```

Comment: logically it can, but its always says error stack trace every i do more trim

here i trim again : 
 String link2=(link.substring(2, link.length()-1));
 String link3=(link2.substring(1,link2.length()-1));

the error says stack trace every i trim more than link2 mate